# How to use vue components in nativescript-vue popups?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I open the popup in some root component like this:

```
import parentt from "./parentt.vue";
.
.
.
this.$showModal(parentt, {
  fullscreen: true,
});
```

This is the content of `parentt.vue`:

```
<template>
  <StackLayout>
    <label text="parent" />
    <!-- <child /> -->
  </StackLayout>
</template>

<script>
  import child from "./child.vue";
  export default {
    components: [child],
  };
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

This is the content of `child.vue`:

```
<template>
  <StackLayout>
    <label text="child" />
  </StackLayout>
</template>

<script>
  export default {};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Whith `<child />` commented out I get a popup with text parent in it.

with `<child />` being there I get a white screen.

I'm using many components in different places in my code, it's only here in a popup that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong bracket in components object in `parentt.vue`. Components is an object, thus use braces instead of the square brackets.

So, the correct script section looks like in `parentt.vue`:

```
<script>
  import child from "./child.vue";
  export default {
    components: {
       child
    },
  };
</script>
```

I recommend for detailed informations the [official vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)

Comment: I don't think the name really matters... the problem was with the bracket:( my heart is broken. It took 3 hours from me. Wouldn't I have gotten an error if I had used vue-debugger?

Comment: You can use for these purpose the browser console or your command line tool.

Comment: I'm not using a browser. It's a nativescript app.